# Null reference with 2 instance classes trying to work together

Tags: c#, instance, nullreferenceexception

main

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Worker worker = new Worker();
        worker.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Worker class

```
    public Worker()
    {

    }

    public Navigator Navigator;
    public Scraper Scraper;

    public void ResetVariables()
    {
        Navigator = new Navigator(this);
        Scraper = new Scraper(this);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        ResetVariables();
        Navigator.SetHtml();
    }
```

Navigator class

```
    private Worker Worker;
    private Scraper Scraper;

    public string Html;

    public Navigator()
    {

    }

    public Navigator(Worker worker)
    {
        Worker = worker;
        Scraper = worker.Scraper;
    }

    public void SetHtml()
    {
        Html = "navigator has changed its html";
        Scraper.ReadHtmlFromNavigator(); //CAUSES NULL REFERENCE IF CALLED INISIDE THIS METHOD
    }
```

Scraper class

```
    private Worker Worker;
    private Navigator Navigator;

    public Scraper()
    {

    }

    public Scraper(Worker worker)
    {
        Worker = worker;
        Navigator = Worker.Navigator;
    }

    public void ReadHtmlFromNavigator()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("scraper reading html from navigator: " + Navigator.Html);
    }
```

When i call Scraper.ReadHtmlFromNavigator() from inside the navigator itself i get a null reference, but if i call it from the worker class it works fine:

```
public void Start()
    {
        ResetVariables();
        Navigator.SetHtml();
        Scraper.ReadHtmlFromNavigator();
    }
```

and i get the output:

```
scraper reading html from navigator: navigator has changed its html
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer - Do not store reference to Navigator inside Scraper and do not store reference to Scraper inside Navigator. Use reference to Worker instead.

In the method `SetHtml` call `Worker.Scraper.ReadHtmlFromNavigator()` instead of `Scraper.ReadHtmlFromNavigator()`

UPDATE:
If you don't want to type `Woker.XXX` every time, you may create some shortcuts:

```
private Navigator Navigator { get { return Worker.Navigator; } }
private Navigator Scraper{ get { return Worker.Scraper; } }
```

Comment: True, i was doing that before but was looking for a way to not type Worker everytime i needed things from other classes, but anyways i was not really bothered by that as it still seemed clean.

Comment: @JoaoVitor see update in my answer how to create shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

You are first constructing a new navigator before you have a scraper:

```
public void ResetVariables()
{
    Navigator = new Navigator(this);
    Scraper = new Scraper(this);
}
```

So your navigator constructor sets its *scraper* variable to a worker.scraper that is not there yet.

Simpy change the order and you should be fine:

```
public void ResetVariables()
{
    Scraper = new Scraper(this);
    Navigator = new Navigator(this);
}
```

In general, though, rethink how you set up your application. This kind of undocumented obligatory sequences create problems and are a code smell.

Comment: yeah i did that as a solution but yes it seems ugly, so i thought of having a "SetInitialReferences()" method in the Navigator and Scraper and then setting those references there after constructing the classes.